# Editing a broken symlink is relinking it to the previously deleted target file

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, symlink

I have a symlink `file4.txt` that was linked to a target file(`file3.txt`) initially.
Once I removed the target file, my symlink got broken as expected as shown in image below.

[image]

But, when I try to write something again to the broken link, the link is getting relinked to a target file with the same name (file3.txt in my case) with all the contents copied (as shown in image below).
[image]

I am very new to linux and trying to figure out the reason as to why and how is this happening. Why a deleted file is again getting created and being re-linked to same symlink again that was broken earlier. Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: I get different results. Can you show which distro, shell and version, VB, and file system you are on? My Bash `>` redirect creates a file as named by the broken link, but it gets fresh inode, timestamps and data. Also, how did your `cat >` terminate? Mine lets me type data and needs Ctrl-D to end.

Answer (score 3):

If `file4.txt` is a symlink to `file3.txt` then `file4.txt` (pathname) resolves to `file3.txt` (pathname) for any tool that doesn't act on the symbolic link itself. See [Pathname Resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13).

This means your `cat > file4.txt` acted as `cat > file3.txt` would. Such command tries to create `file3.txt` if it's not already there. The new `file3.txt` (file) has nothing to do with the old (deleted) `file3.txt` (file), except the new file is, and the old file was accessible as `file3.txt` (pathname).

Any symlink points to some path by storing it internally as text. It does not directly point to a file or inode; it points to some path, taken or not, making sense in the directory tree [or not](https://superuser.com/q/1748750/432690). In your case, once `file3.txt` gets created anew, your symlink becomes valid. The new file is not the old file, but it's accessible via the same pathname and this matters to the symlink. If you instead created a directory named `file3.txt` then the symlink would point to the directory from then on.

Comment: I am interested as to where the two "writing to broken link ..." messages come from, especially the second one (where `cat` is reading *and* the file has already been newly created).

Comment: @Paul_Pedant This is what the OP *typed*. The first such line is the input echoed by the terminal driver, apparently with Enter and followed by Ctrl+D, so `cat` terminated. The second such line is the content of the file at that time. The OP can have typed `Hello World!` or anything instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I think I got it now. Just a small doubt though, what do you mean when you say `any tool that doesn't act on symbolic link itself` ?

Comment: @AnantShekhar Many tools, when given a symlink, dereference it, as if they were given the target of the symlink. Some tools act on the symlink itself. E.g. if `foo` is a symlink to `/`, `file foo` in my Kubuntu yields `foo: symbolic link to /`. This means it perceives the symlink as a symlink, it acts on the symlink itself. `file -L foo` dereferences the symlink and yields `foo: directory`, it acts on the target. Another example: `mv foo bar` moves (renames) the symlink, not the directory. But `cp foo bar` would see `foo` as a directory; I need `cp -P` to make a copy of the symlink itself.